# Usage of the "too ... to" structure

Tags: idioms

Do the following sentences make sense to you:

(1) "No people are too old but too lazy to learn."

(2) "There are no people too old but too lazy to learn."

What I mean to say is you can always learn no matter how old you are, unless you are too lazy.

And if they do make sense, are they grammar wise acceptable?

Thank you so much.

Comment: No. Go with 'what you want to say'. Or "No people are too old (though some are certainly too lazy, no matter what their age) to learn."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand what you're trying to say without having to read your explanation, but grammatically it doesn't make much sense. If you didn't want to completely depart from your wording, an acceptable paraphrase could be:

> "People aren't too old to learn but too lazy".

**EDIT after your Edit**:
Both sentences are struggling to sound right because you're trying to define an action that has no subject. By saying "No People" you take away the subject of your sentence. Hence why starting the sentence as I did and adding the negative characteristic to the subject 'People' sounds better.

Comment: I learned today. Much obliged for your detailed and informative explanation.

Comment: @Kevin glad I could help!